# What part is a big blue hot tub piece?

Tags: part-identification

I was wandering around on Bricklink the other day and I found a very large round transparent blue (light or dark?) basin that could be used to do a hot tub party.  I can't find it now. I think it was 10 X something.  Does anyone know this part?

Comment: Be careful about wandering around on Bricklink unaccompanied.  You never know when you might fall in a vat of bricks never to be seen again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one [47674](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47674&idColor=74#T=C&C=74) [image] or this one [47674](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47674&idColor=14#T=C&C=14) [image]

These are X-POD containers.